# POST name via PDO

Tags: php, html

I managed to do the if, but now the variable `$nome` isn't getting any value and so my if/else isn't working the way it should.

PHP code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['nom'])){
$nome = $_POST['nom'];
}
    $db_host        = 'localhost';
    $db_user        = 'root';
    $db_pass        = '';
    $db_database    = 'crc'; 
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
    if (empty($nome)){
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM perfumesh ORDER BY ref ASC ");
    }
    else{
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM perfumesh WHERE nome='$nome'");
    }
        $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
<tr class="record">

    <td><?php echo $row['ref']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['preco']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

INPUT code:

```
Nome: <input type = "text" name = "nom" id="nome" placeholder="Procurar por nome">
<input type = "submit" value = "Procurar">
```

When I execute the code the variable `$nome` is always empty. What I want is when a person inserts a name to search, it loads that name and when the textbox is empty it shows all the data from the db.

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST['nom']` has a value? Otherwise `$nome` always will be empty. If it is not set (check with `echo $_POST['nom']` in the beginning of your script) your form might not be posting correctly.

Comment: Has your form a `method="post"`? try `var_dump($nome);` right after `$nome=$_POST['nom];`

Comment: The var is always empty that's the problem. @Michel

Comment: And no it isn't on a form, should it be in one? @dimlucas

Comment: @fabimetabi Unless you use AJAX to run the script, you need to include the `input`s in a `<form></form>`

Comment: Take a look at the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) for handling forms.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah the problem is that I hadn't done the `<form></form>`